# Can I replace "GET" methods with "POST" everywhere in the codebase?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm maintaining web application and we had caching problems with IE (information was cached because GET was used). The problem was resolved that in IE's Developers Tool *Always refresh from server* was turned on on users' side. The problem was not reproducible in our side but I have suspicion that the XMLHttpRequest() could have been called with POST as a workaround.

So I have a question. Am I risking something if I replace all GET methods with POST? The intention is to avoid cache everywhere where it is possible.

My first tests show the same behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I risking something if I replace all GET methods with POST?

Pressing Back will trigger "Are you sure you want to resubmit the form?" messages and you'll make it impossible to bookmark or link to specific pages.

If you want to control caching, use [cache control headers](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: This is a live production application. We do not allow to use "Back" button

Comment: @user3719454 — Sounds like a design bug.

Comment: okay, so except this design bug using POST will change nothing in the functionality, right?